# Centering Headers in a Siunitx Column with Uncertainties

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, header-footer, siunitx

I have been stuck on this problem for the last two hours, scouring this forum for any tips. Nothing has worked.

I want to present a table with uncertainties. I am describing the performance of models, so I need to display the standard deviation as a measure of the stability of the models. This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true, tight-spacing=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Why won't the headers just align to the centre?}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{%
                    l
                    *{3}{S}[table-format=1.5(5)]
                }
                \toprule
                {Thing} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Statistic 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Statistic 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Statistic 3} \\
                \midrule
                One thing & 0.77442\pm0.00123 & 0.98234\pm0.00033 & 0.99971\pm0.00011 \\
                Second thing & 0.46622\pm0.04567 & 0.91248\pm0.01203 & 0.99925\pm0.00022 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I had thought this would work, but irritatingly it produces headers that are offset. I added the `\multicolumn` command to try to fix it, but it doesn't work. I had thought it was the uncertainties, so I played around with the `table-format` option, but nothing seems to do it. The spacing is all off anyway, so I suspect I am doing something stupid.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want three columns with `S[table-format=1.5(5)]`, but your input actually specifies

```
SSS[table-format=1.5(5)]
```

because you have a misplaced `}`. You want

```
*{3}{S[table-format=1.5(5)]}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true, tight-spacing=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{The headers align to the centre}

\begin{tabular}{%
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.5(5)]} %%% <----- HERE
}
\toprule
{Thing} & {Statistic 1} & {Statistic 2} & {Statistic 3} \\
\midrule
One thing    & 0.77442\pm0.00123 & 0.98234\pm0.00033 & 0.99971\pm0.00011 \\
Second thing & 0.46622\pm0.04567 & 0.91248\pm0.01203 & 0.99925\pm0.00022 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am an abject fool. Thank you so much!